# Optimizing SQL Server 2012 Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that runs for 12 hours.

The query does left joins on 5 tables and reports on a bunch of monthly metrics. Here is the query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YYYY,Referral_dt) AS RefYear, DATEPART(MM,Referral_dt) AS RefMonth, 
        CASE 
            WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '4/14/2013' THEN 'Q1' 
            WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '4/15/2013' AND '7/14/2013' THEN 'Q2'
            WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '7/15/2013' AND '9/30/2013' THEN 'Q3' 
            WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '10/1/2013' AND '12/31/2013' THEN 'Q4'
            WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '4/14/2014' THEN 'Q1' 
            WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '4/15/2014' AND '7/14/2014' THEN 'Q2'
            WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '7/15/2014' AND '9/30/2014' THEN 'Q3' 
            WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '12/31/2014' THEN 'Q4'
        ELSE 'X' END as RefQtr, 
        crm.salesstatuscode, crm.Referral_State, crm.lead_source, mp.mcc_desc, mp.mcc_industry, sr.manager_name, sr.payrollname, 
        sr.region as Sales_Region,sr.market as Sales_Market, sr.saleschannel as SalesChannel, Bk.SuperRegion_Name as Bank_SuperRegion, 
        Bk.Region_Name as Bank_Region ,Bk.Division_Name as Bank_Division,
        sum(case when crm.referral_state = 'Won' then 1 else 0 end) as referrals_won, sum(sv.projected_profit) as prj_profit,
        sum(case when mp.proposal_Date is null then 0 else 1 end) as proposals_created, sum(ac.signed_annual_volume) as total_signed_volume,  
        sum(case when ac.Acct_Act_Date is null then 0 else 1 end) as activated_accounts, COUNT(*)  as referral_count
        into moagg1
FROM kaiserver.dbKAI.dbo.Referrals_CRM CRM 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.merchant_id, CAST(p.proposal_create_dt as date) as Proposal_Date, m.mcc_desc, m.mcc_industry 
                from kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[proposals] p 
                left join (SELECT mcc, mcc_desc, mcc_industry from kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[merchantcategorycode]) m
                 on p.mcc = m.mcc where datepart(yyyy,proposal_create_dt) in ('2013', '2014')) mp
      ON crm.merchant_id = mp.merchant_id
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_no, CAST(Account_Activate_dt as date) as Acct_Act_Date, signed_annual_volume, average_tkt
                from kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[Account]
                where current_ind=1 and datepart(yyyy,account_submit_dt) in ('2013', '2014')) ac
     ON crm.account_no = ac.account_no
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT e1.repid, e1.repcode, e1.payrollname, e1.salesmanager, e2.payrollname as manager_name,
            e1.region,e1.market, e1.saleschannel
             FROM   [fdserver].fdms.[dbo].[tbl_reps] e1 LEFT JOIN [fdserver].fdms.[dbo].[tbl_reps] e2 
                    ON e1.salesmanager = e2.repid
             WHERE e1.market not like ('%TEST%') and e1.payrollname is not null and e1.region is not null and e1.market is not null) SR 
     ON CRM.Sales_Rep_Cd = SR.Repcode
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT [AU_name], [AU_Code] ,[SuperRegion_Name], [Region_Name] ,[Division_Name],
                    [SubDivision_Name] ,[District_Name] ,[SubDistrict_Name]
             FROM kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[BankAU_Hierarchy]
             WHERE [Reporting_Interval_Id] = '201410') BK 
    ON CRM.referral_au = BK.AU_code
    LEFT JOIN (select merchantnumber, projected_profit from kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[SoldVolumeDetail]) sv
    ON crm.account_no = sv.merchantnumber
    WHERE DATEPART(YYYY, Referral_dt) in ('2013', '2014')
          AND (crm.salesstatuscode <> 'DUPL' or crm.salesstatuscode is null) 
          AND crm.lead_source not in ('Test Lead', 'Bank Lead Placeholder')
    group by DATEPART(YYYY,Referral_dt), DATEPART(MM,Referral_dt), crm.Referral_State, crm.salesstatuscode, crm.lead_source, mp.mcc_desc, 
    mp.mcc_industry, sr.manager_name, sr.payrollname, sr.region,sr.market, sr.saleschannel, Bk.SuperRegion_Name, Bk.Region_Name ,Bk.Division_Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '4/14/2013' THEN 'Q1' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '4/15/2013' AND '7/14/2013' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '7/15/2013' AND '9/30/2013' THEN 'Q3' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '10/1/2013' AND '12/31/2013' THEN 'Q4'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '4/14/2014' THEN 'Q1' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '4/15/2014' AND '7/14/2014' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '7/15/2014' AND '9/30/2014' THEN 'Q3' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '12/31/2014' THEN 'Q4'
    ELSE 'X' END
```

When I run the full query as above, it runs for 12 hours. But when I run the query for 1 month, it runs in 8 minutes. So I want to run the query for each month and append into one file. That should make this query run in 2-3 hours.

I can use `union` and copy the code 24 times but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it. Is there a more programattic way to do this?

UPDATE: I want to be able to run this query every day to update the latest month's numbers.

Comment: Please post your execution plan.

Comment: I can do `select....where month = 1 and year=2013 union all select....where month = 2 and year=2013 union all...`etc for each month. Is that what you meant by execution plan?

Comment: No it's not.  Google "SQL Server Execution Plan"

Comment: To @AbeMiessler's point, we need the execution plan and any applicable table structure/index information.

Comment: Are you sure that you're joining the tables correctly...?

Comment: thanks, I have the execution plan. how do I paste it? it shows up as a flow chart. I also pasted the actual query instead of the skeleton sample I had earlier.

Comment: Are you going across linked servers to do JOINs?

Comment: @Moosa - take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190646.aspx

Comment: @AbeMiessler the execution plan is too big to paste as an image or as xml. But 97% of the cost shows up in a step called "Hash Match (Partial aggregate)". Does that help. I don't know what it means.

Comment: Can you drop it into something like pastebin and then provide the link here?

Comment: @AbeMiessler http://pastebin.com/v5Hrs41e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of the execution plan you posted I think you have a missing join predicate and are generating a ton of intermediate rows:

[image: query plan]

Here's the same query cleaned up slightly (CTEs instead of correlated subqueries and replaced the CASE statement with DATEPART(QUARTER)), it might make it easier to tell where your missing predicate is:

```
WITH
m as (SELECT mcc, mcc_desc, mcc_industry from kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[merchantcategorycode]),
mp as (SELECT p.merchant_id, CAST(p.proposal_create_dt as date) as Proposal_Date, m.mcc_desc, m.mcc_industry 
    from kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[proposals] p 
    left join m on p.mcc = m.mcc where datepart(yyyy,proposal_create_dt) in ('2013', '2014')),
ac as (SELECT account_no, CAST(Account_Activate_dt as date) as Acct_Act_Date, signed_annual_volume, average_tkt
    from kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[Account]
    where current_ind=1 and datepart(yyyy,account_submit_dt) in ('2013', '2014')),
sr as (SELECT e1.repid, e1.repcode, e1.payrollname, e1.salesmanager, e2.payrollname as manager_name, e1.region,e1.market, e1.saleschannel
    FROM [fdserver].fdms.[dbo].[tbl_reps] e1
    LEFT JOIN [fdserver].fdms.[dbo].[tbl_reps] e2 ON e1.salesmanager = e2.repid
    WHERE e1.market not like ('%TEST%') and e1.payrollname is not null and e1.region is not null and e1.market is not null),
bk as (SELECT [AU_name], [AU_Code], [SuperRegion_Name], [Region_Name] ,[Division_Name], [SubDivision_Name], [District_Name], [SubDistrict_Name]
    FROM kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[BankAU_Hierarchy]
    WHERE [Reporting_Interval_Id] = '201410'),
sv as (select merchantnumber, projected_profit from kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[SoldVolumeDetail])

SELECT DATEPART(YYYY,Referral_dt) AS RefYear, DATEPART(MM,Referral_dt) AS RefMonth, DATEPART(QUARTER, Referral_dt) as RefQtr,
    crm.salesstatuscode, crm.Referral_State, crm.lead_source, mp.mcc_desc, mp.mcc_industry, sr.manager_name, sr.payrollname,
    sr.region as Sales_Region,sr.market as Sales_Market, sr.saleschannel as SalesChannel, Bk.SuperRegion_Name as Bank_SuperRegion,
    Bk.Region_Name as Bank_Region ,Bk.Division_Name as Bank_Division,
    sum(case when crm.referral_state = 'Won' then 1 else 0 end) as referrals_won, sum(sv.projected_profit) as prj_profit,
    sum(case when mp.proposal_Date is null then 0 else 1 end) as proposals_created, sum(ac.signed_annual_volume) as total_signed_volume,  
    sum(case when ac.Acct_Act_Date is null then 0 else 1 end) as activated_accounts, COUNT(*) as referral_count INTO moagg1
FROM kaiserver.dbKAI.dbo.Referrals_CRM CRM
LEFT JOIN mp ON crm.merchant_id = mp.merchant_id
LEFT JOIN ac ON crm.account_no = ac.account_no
LEFT JOIN sr ON crm.sales_rep_cd = sr.repcode
LEFT JOIN bk ON crm.referral_au = ck.au_code
LEFT JOIN sv ON crm.account_no = sv.merchantnumber

WHERE DATEPART(YYYY, Referral_dt) in ('2013', '2014')
    AND (crm.salesstatuscode <> 'DUPL' or crm.salesstatuscode is null) 
    AND crm.lead_source not in ('Test Lead', 'Bank Lead Placeholder')

group by DATEPART(YYYY,Referral_dt), DATEPART(MM,Referral_dt), crm.Referral_State, crm.salesstatuscode, crm.lead_source, mp.mcc_desc, 
    mp.mcc_industry, sr.manager_name, sr.payrollname, sr.region,sr.market, sr.saleschannel, Bk.SuperRegion_Name, Bk.Region_Name ,Bk.Division_Name,
    DATEPART(QUARTER, Referral_dt)
```

Comment: @Moosa any join where the condition may be selecting more records than you expect, e.g.: crm.referrals_au = ck.au_code takes 121M and 30K and produces 360B - if that's high it could be that several different records with matching au_code are being cross joined. To eliminate them you would need to provide additional criteria for the join.

Comment: For context, AU is a store. In the AU example you gave, the crm table has sales by AU at the transaction level and the AU table has AU name.So crm has AU code mutliple times and the join is cross joining. Is this what you mean? i.e. so if an AU has 100 records in CRM, it is doing 100 joins, right? And that's causing the poor performance? If so, how would I rewrite that join?

Comment: As I typed that I realized that it makes sense to first aggregate crm by month and then do the join. Will try it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Moosa that sounds like the problem. If you're not expecting additional rows from what's in referrals_crm it would make sense for each of the subqueries to group by the column being used to join them to referrals_crm

Answer (score 0):

I think this produces identical output and it should be faster. Also, you need to ensure every field that is used for a JOIN or in the WHERE clause is indexed.

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(YYYY,Referral_dt) AS RefYear, DATEPART(MM,Referral_dt) AS RefMonth, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '4/14/2013' THEN 'Q1' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '4/15/2013' AND '7/14/2013' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '7/15/2013' AND '9/30/2013' THEN 'Q3' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '10/1/2013' AND '12/31/2013' THEN 'Q4'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '4/14/2014' THEN 'Q1' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '4/15/2014' AND '7/14/2014' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '7/15/2014' AND '9/30/2014' THEN 'Q3' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '12/31/2014' THEN 'Q4'
    ELSE 'X' END as RefQtr, 
    crm.salesstatuscode, crm.Referral_State, crm.lead_source, m.mcc_desc, m.mcc_industry, e2.manager_name, e1.payrollname, 
    e1.region as Sales_Region,e1.market as Sales_Market, e1.saleschannel as SalesChannel, Bk.SuperRegion_Name as Bank_SuperRegion, 
    Bk.Region_Name as Bank_Region ,Bk.Division_Name as Bank_Division,
    sum(case when crm.referral_state = 'Won' then 1 else 0 end) as referrals_won, sum(sv.projected_profit) as prj_profit,
    sum(case when p.proposal_Date is null then 0 else 1 end) as proposals_created, sum(ac.signed_annual_volume) as total_signed_volume,  
    sum(case when ac.Acct_Act_Date is null then 0 else 1 end) as activated_accounts, COUNT(*)  as referral_count
into moagg1
FROM kaiserver.dbKAI.dbo.Referrals_CRM CRM 
LEFT kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[proposals] p  ON crm.merchant_id = p.merchant_id
    AND datepart(yyyy,p.proposal_create_dt) in ('2013', '2014')
left join kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[merchantcategorycode] m on p.mcc = m.mcc
LEFT JOIN kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[Account] ac ON crm.account_no = ac.account_no
    AND ac.current_ind=1
    AND and datepart(yyyy,ac.account_submit_dt) in ('2013', '2014')
LEFT JOIN [fdserver].fdms.[dbo].[tbl_reps] e1 ON e1.repcode=CRM.Sales_Rep_Cd
    AND e1.market not like ('%TEST%')
    and e1.payrollname is not null
    and e1.region is not null
    and e1.market is not null
LEFT JOIN [fdserver].fdms.[dbo].[tbl_reps] e2 ON e1.salesmanager = e2.repid
LEFT JOIN kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[BankAU_Hierarchy]  BK ON CRM.referral_au = BK.AU_code
    AND [Reporting_Interval_Id] = '201410'
LEFT JOIN kaiserver.[dbKAI].[dbo].[SoldVolumeDetail] sv ON crm.account_no = sv.merchantnumber
WHERE DATEPART(YYYY, CRM.Referral_dt) in ('2013', '2014')
AND ISNULL(crm.salesstatuscode,'') <> 'DUPL'
AND crm.lead_source not in ('Test Lead', 'Bank Lead Placeholder')
group by DATEPART(YYYY,Referral_dt), DATEPART(MM,Referral_dt), crm.Referral_State, crm.salesstatuscode, crm.lead_source, mp.mcc_desc, 
    mp.mcc_industry, sr.manager_name, sr.payrollname, sr.region,sr.market, sr.saleschannel, Bk.SuperRegion_Name, Bk.Region_Name ,Bk.Division_Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '4/14/2013' THEN 'Q1' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '4/15/2013' AND '7/14/2013' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '7/15/2013' AND '9/30/2013' THEN 'Q3' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '10/1/2013' AND '12/31/2013' THEN 'Q4'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '1/1/2014' AND '4/14/2014' THEN 'Q1' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '4/15/2014' AND '7/14/2014' THEN 'Q2'
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '7/15/2014' AND '9/30/2014' THEN 'Q3' 
        WHEN CAST(Referral_dt as date) BETWEEN '10/1/2014' AND '12/31/2014' THEN 'Q4'
    ELSE 'X' END
```

Comment: Thanks but splitting up e1 and e2 joins doesn't work because that's an employee table and I needed to do a self-join to get manager name for each employee. I need to tinker with this to test...there were also alias naming errors in the select and group by clause due to the splitting of joins.

Comment: @Moosa Based on the original SQL, I'm not seeing a self-join for employee. Sorry if I missed any aliases, I thought I got them all as I refactored.